# AUTH in next js with React Query

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, react-query

Tell me I want to make middleware to protect the administrator pages, I have authorization through sessions on the project. The project itself is on next js . I want to use React Query to protect pages, but I get the error: An error has occurred: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 react query

APi:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { route } from 'next/dist/server/router'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import checkSession from '../../src/services/checkCookie'

export async function middleware(req: NextApiRequest,res:NextApiResponse) {
 if (req.method === 'GET') {
  try {
    const router= useRouter()
    const sid = req.cookies['sid']
    const admin = await checkSession(sid)
    console.log(router.pathname)
    // if (router.pathname === '/admin/login' || router.pathname === '/admin/regAdmin' || admin) {
    //     return res.next()
    // }
    res.send(admin)
    const host = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.HOST : 'http://localhost:3000'
    // return  res.redirect(host + '/admin/login')
    return  res.send({ redirectUrl: '/admin/login' })
  }catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Server error" })
  }
 }else{
    res.status(404).send({ message: "adress error" })
 }
}
```

Service in api (checkSessin) :

```
export default async function checkSession (token: string) {
    // const token = req.cookies['sid']
    if (typeof window === 'undefined' && token) {
        const unsign = (await import('./signature')).unsign
        const sessionToken = unsign(token, process.env.SECRET!)
        if (sessionToken && typeof sessionToken === 'string') {
            const db = (await import('../../prisma')).default
            const session = db.session.findUnique({ where: { sessionToken }, 
                include: { admin: true } })
            if (session) {
                return { admin: session.admin }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

page admin :

```
import { NextPage } from "next"
import AdminLayout from "../../src/component/admin/AdminLayout"
import { SalesAdminComponent } from "../../src/component/admin/SalesAdmin"
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'


const  AdminTable: NextPage = () => {

  const { isLoading, error, data,isSuccess} = useQuery('sid', () =>
   fetch('api/checkSession',{
    method:'GET',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
   }).then(res =>res.json())
  )
    if (isLoading) return 'Loading...'
    if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message

    return (
      <>
       {isSuccess &&
        <AdminLayout title="OPEL Admin">
            <SalesAdminComponent />
        </AdminLayout>
       }
       {isLoading && <p>Loading..</p>}
       {error && <p>Error occurred!</p>}
      </>
    )
  }

  export default AdminTable
```

Comment: Where exactly are you expecting the `token` value to come from in `checkSession`?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things are going on here. The response is probably an HTML page that cannot be parsed to JSON. Please include logs both from the server and the browser.

Also, why are you using the client router on the server?